# ¿Como mostrar ocultar DIV con jQuery?

Tags: jquery, div

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual creo un formulario con un select principal, dependiendo de la opción en el select que lo toma de una tabla, se muestren ciertos campos del formulario y tengo este código:

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
      {% if form.errors %}
         <div class="col col-md-12 alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
             <h3><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Error!</h3>
               {{ form.errors }}
         </div>
         {% endif %}
         <div class="col col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="tipoaccion">Tipo Accion</label>
               {{form.tipoaccion}}                                    
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="permiso" class="row divOculto">                                                                                         
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <label for="pphora_ini">Hora de Inicio:</label>
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  {{form.pphora_ini}}
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="pphora_fin">Hora de Fin:</label>
                   {{form.pphora_fin}}
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pp_goce">Goce de Sueldo</label>
                  {{form.pp_goce}}
               </div>
            </div>                            
         </div>
         <div id="incapacidad" class="row divOculto">
             <div class="col col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="infecha_ini">Fecha Inicio</label>
                     {{form.infecha_ini}}
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col col-md-2">
                <label for="infecha_fin">Fecha Fin</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    {{form.infecha_fin}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-md-4">
                  <label for="indocumento">Documento Incapacidad</label>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                     </div>
                     {{form.indocumento}}
                  </div>
              </div>                            
           </div>
           <div id="traslado" class="row divOculto">
              <div class="col col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="trdepartamento">Departamento Traslado</label>
                     {{form.trdepartamento}}
                 </div>
              <div class="col col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="trfecha_tras">Fecha Traslado:</label>
                     <div class="input-group date" id="trfecha_tras" data-target-input="nearest">
                         {{form.trfecha_tras}}
                         <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#trfecha_tras" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
              </div>                                                                    
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success float-right">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Este es el archivo jQuery, en el que apunto al ID del Select y le digo que cuando cambie me muestre un div y me oculte otros

```
$(function() {
   $("#id_tipoaccion").on('change', function() {

     let optionAction = $(this).val();
     alert(optionAction);
     switch (optionAction) {

       case "1":
         $("#permiso").show();
         $("#incapacidad").hide();
         $("#traslado").hide();
         break;

       case "2":
         $("#permiso").hide();
         $("#incapacidad").show();
         $("#traslado").hide();
         break;

       case "3":
         $("#permiso").hide();
         $("#incapacidad").hide();
         $("#traslado").show();
         break;

     }

   });
 });
```

El código que genera del SELECT es el siguiente (el que tiene como id="id_tipoaccion"); el alert no lo muestra.

```
<select name="tipoaccion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="id_tipoaccion">
```

No he podido hacer que se muestren los div's, pues tengo una clase CSS únicamente con el atributo dysplay:none que los oculta todos cuando inicia la pagina. Realmente no se que estoy haciendo mal, alguna sugerencia seria mas que agradecida, de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Agrega el código HTML que genera del `select` para saber el `ID` y `name` que tienen. También que mensaje te manda en el  `alert()`

Comment: @MrDev gracias por tu pronta respuesta, he actualizado la pregunta y agregado los comentarios que me hiciste. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba , poniendo un alert dentro de tu funcion para verificar que te está reconociendo el evento 'change'

```
$("#id_tipoaccion").on('change', function() {
 alert("abc")
});
```

Si el alert no se muestra podría ser porque no tienes cargado el Jquery o necesitas hacerlo de esta manera .

```
$(document).on('change',"#id_tipoaccion" function() {
```

Si el alert se muestra, verifica que los ids que estás poniendo esten bien escritos  y existan
o alguno de tus id está mal escrito o no está definido

Abre la consola del navegador y verifica si te muestra algún error

Comment: Mauro, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, te comento que hice los cambios que me sugieres y el problema persiste, debo decirte que he revisado también si tengo cargado jquery y puedo decirte que otras funciones de jquery me funcionan, realmente no se cual es el problema y abro la consola y no me dice nada, y mucho menos muestra el alert.

Ayuda please!

Answer (score 0):

He podido resolver mi problema, para los que tengan el mismo problema les dejo la solución que funciono para mi.

```
$("select[name='tipoaccion']").change(function(){
var optionAction = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
//alert("Ha seleccionado - " + optionAction); 

   switch (optionAction) {

     case "1":
       $("#permiso").show();
       $("#incapacidad").hide();
       $("#traslado").hide();
       break;

     case "3":
       $("#permiso").hide();
       $("#incapacidad").show();
       $("#traslado").hide();
       break;

     case "5":
       $("#permiso").hide();
       $("#incapacidad").hide();
       $("#traslado").show();
       break;

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Que tal si pruebas algo asi? (ejemplo de como lo uso):

```
    function cambiarConformeLaOpcion() {
        if ($('#elIdSelect').val() == 1) {
            $('#campoOcultar').show();
        } else {
            $('#campoOcultar').hide();
        }
    }
    $('#elIdSelect').change(cambiarConformeLaOpcion);
```

Dice que si el value (la opcion) de el id del select es igual a 1 (en tu aso seria el value del select que necesitas) entonces muestre el campo con id campoOcultar y si no que lo oculte. Despues liga la funcion a un change (que cambie) en funcion al id del select. En tu caso creo que seria asi:

```
function nombreFuncion() {
    if ($('#id_tipoaccion').val() == 1) {
        $("#permiso").show();
        $("#incapacidad").hide();
        $("#traslado").hide();
    }
    if ($('#id_tipoaccion').val() == 3) {
        $("#permiso").hide();
        $("#incapacidad").show();
        $("#traslado").hide();
    }
    if ($('#id_tipoaccion').val() == 5) {
        $("#permiso").hide();
        $("#incapacidad").hide();
        $("#traslado").show();
    }
}
$('#id_tipoaccion').change(nombreFuncion);
```

Bueno, espero me hayas entendido la idea